# Can I use swipe-to-delete feature in custom uitableviewcell?

Tags: ios, ios6, uitableview

I tried it but swiping doesn't trigger tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath: at all! and delete button never appears, is there a workaround for this?

EDIT: This is my implementation

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     return YES;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        if(_itemsArray == nil)
            NSLog(@"\n\nNIL ARRAY\n\n");
        NSLog(@"\nindexPath.row = %d\nItemsArray Count:%d",indexPath.row,_itemsArray.count);
        int row = [[[_itemsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"itemRow"] integerValue];
        [_itemsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [[self delegate]didDeletedBillItemRow:row];
    }

    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: disable user interaction in custom tableview cell

Comment: enable tableview.setEditing = YES;

Answer (score 7):

`tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:` is not the right place to handle this. From the official documentation, You need to implement this method in you UITableViewController :

> **Note:** To enable the swipe-to-delete feature of table views (wherein a
>   user swipes horizontally across a row to display a Delete button), you
>   must implement the [tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView%3acommitEditingStyle%3aforRowAtIndexPath%3a)
>   method.

Just like that:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        //add code here for when you hit delete
    }    
}
```

Comment: also make sure to return YES in tableview:canEditRowAtIndexPath:

Comment: tableview:canEditRowAtIndexPath returns YES and tableView:commitEditingStyle: is implemented